# Perl parsing JSON code - why is my path wrong?

Tags: json, perl, parsing, syntax-error, web-crawler

I have been parsing json code found here: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Name%20Tag/render/?count=10&start=10 and trying to extract information from the data. (here is a parser to paste the response into: http://json.parser.online.fr/)

I want to find out the

```
"steamid_lister":"76561198054594560",
```

value.

I am using the following code to do so:

```
use JSON::XS;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Name%20Tag/render/?count=10&start=10";
my $json = get $url;
my $data = decode_json $json;
my @infoids = keys %{$data -> {listinginfo}};
foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
    print $infoid . "\n";
}
foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
    my $price = $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price} ?$data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price} : 0 ; #Problem is here
    print $price . "\n";
}
```

When executed in the command prompt I get:

```
2837579576399030707
2837579576272398122
2828572377224672029
2836453676551501383
2837579576412912762
2837579576057748967
2837579576057701282
2837579576057640907
2837579576412827087
2836453676554468348
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

The first set of numbers are the listing ids which are working fine however the 0s are the problem. I should be getting more numbers so I assume im referencing the "steamid_lister" object wrong on the commented line however im not sure how to fix this problem. Any help would be really greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time
Seb Morris

Comment: There is no `converted_price` key in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is, that you try to access a key which does not exists `converted_price`! Just try it with `price`

```
foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
    my $price = $data->{listinginfo}->{$infoid}->{price} ? $data->{listinginfo}->{$infoid}->{price} : 0;
    print $price . "\n";
}
```